# SQLSTATE=08004 ORA=12154 when use a 32-bit ODBC driver to connect Oracle

Tags: oracle, odbc

on my computer ,a 64-bit windows10,when I use  a 32-bit ODBC driver  to connect Oracle data source ABGGOA ,it feels very slow,I always get the error :Unable to connect SQLState=08004 [Oracle][ODBC][ORA]Ora-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified；but on the same computer,I use a 64-bit ODBC driver to connect the same data source,it works and feels quickly;I had use the 32-bit ODBC to connect another two data source,it always works。I can also use PL/SQL Developer to connect the ABGGOA data source on my computer.I feels confused,don't know what's wrong.
the TNS connect string is:

### OA测试

ABGGOA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.139.8)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = slistest)
    )
  )
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1ft4.png)

Comment: Which ODBC drivers did you use? The driver from Microsoft or from Oracle. Did you install an 64 bit Oracle Client?

Comment: I use the Oracle driver，download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html。the 32 bit Oracle Client contents  instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip and  instantclient-odbc-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip。the 64 bit Oracle Client contents instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip and instantclient-odbc-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip

Comment: I think you mixed up the 32 bit and 64 bit installation, follow [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100) to install both on one machine.

Comment: I have followed the instruction，but it didn't work.I installed the Oracle
  Instant Client,it didn't have ORACLE_HOME and HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1\ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: Which application do you use? It is not possible to use 32bit and 64bit assemblies in the same process. Each process must be exclusively either 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: I want to use 32bit assembly for powerdesiner to update model from database.In another case ,I successed in connecting the database by using 32bit driver,I double there is something constraint in the database。